# Предложения СПП нерасчлененной структуры:

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Правильно ли я нашла в тексте предложения СПП нерасчлененной структуры??? Проверьте, пожалуйста.

1. Мансуров похвалил их за смекалку, что не вместе, не дуром лезли к нему, но попало им за то, что патроны жгут неэкономно.
2. Немцы все силы сосредоточили именно там, где будут переправляться наши войска
3. Нелька задремала, благодарная лейтенанту за то, что он ее воспоминаниями больше не тревожит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложения 2 и 3 относятся к этому типу (придаточная часть в них распространяет "там" и "то" соответственно). Предложение 1 состоит из двух сочинительно связанных (через "но") СПП нерасчленённой структуры: первое распространяет "смекалку", второе - "то".