# СПП нерасчлененной структуры:

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Правильно ли я нашла в тексте предложения СПП??? Проверьте, пожалуйста.

1. Лешка согласно кивнул головой, как будто человек на другом конце провода мог его увидеть.
2. Берег устелен трупами, точно брошенным лесом на сплавной реке.
3. Все это время командир его жалостливо смотрел на своего бойца, как на неразумного и болезного дитятю.

Comment: По-моему, второе и третье - не СПП.  Только в первом есть второе подлежащее ("человек").

Comment: А, может быть, я и не прав.  Вы уже задавали похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418255/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%9f%d0%9f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b ...

Comment: Правильно ли употреблять три знака препинания подряд? Почему три, и не больше? Откуда к нам пришла эта красивая традиция?

Comment: Вообще нет, вы правы. Вместо этого нужно употреблять "?!"

Comment: Правильно. Видимо правильно то, что умеренно.

Answer (score 1):

Среди этих предложений **нет** *СПП нерасчленённой структуры*: только первое предложение можно отнести к СПП, а в нём придаточная часть относится к *главной части в целом* (не к отдельному её члену).

Comment: то есть оно расчлененной структуры?

Comment: Да, расчленённой.